# Make Ctrl+K indent entire lines even when the first and last are only partially highlighted

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting, editor, highlighting, indentation

When we select text for indenting, *e.g.*

[image]

and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>, we get this:

[image]

I don't think our target audience is accustomed to this behavior, although I could be wrong. The following programs indent *entire* lines, as I'd expect:

- Eclipse (tested on Kepler SR1)
- [Ideone](http://ideone.com/) (tested on 2013-10-29)
- NetBeans (tested on version 7.4)
- Notepad++ (tested on version 6.5)
- Sublime Text (tested on version 2.0.2)
- UltraEdit (tested on version 19.10.0.1012)
- vi(m)—well, in this case, the Visual block already extends to the beginning of the line.

I know this is really minor, but every time it happens to me (a few times a week, though my brain might be filtering more frequent occurences) I tell myself I'll post on meta and  I never do, so... here it is.

---

P.S. When only *one* line is highlighted, Eclipse, Notepad++, Sublime Text, and UltraEdit all simply replace that portion with a tab, which makes sense in their contexts, but doesn't apply here. Stack Exchange backticks the selection in that case, which I think makes sense and should stay.

Comment: I expect Ctrl-K to delete the entire line starting from point, so... yeah.

Comment: Netbeans also functions the way you describe

Comment: Please, no. I find this useful enough (and have used it before) to not replace it by functionality one can already get by simply moving the mouse a little more, or pressing a key or two more. What's the problem anyway? - You do this once, see it doesn't work the way you thought, and don't do it again.

Comment: None of your example tools, as far as I'm aware, are intended to mix code and non-code in the same file. It would be better to compare it to web tools, where such an intention exists (don't ask me which tool, though).

Comment: @Dukeling - That's a good point, that IDEs and code editors aren't intended for use with mixed content. Regarding your comment that users should _"simply move the mouse a little more"_ though, hm... I don't mean to undermine your preference, but couldn't I also argue that _you_ could simply hit Enter before Ctrl+K'ing, if the functionality were the other way around? My point is---not an attack on your preference---but just that, either way, it's very little work. I was hoping (perhaps wrongly!) that what IDEs and code editors already do, would be what's natural to the majority of users.

Comment: @acheong87 I don't feel particularly strongly about the way it's working now, it's just that changing things is *always* more work than keeping them the same, so I'd rather have SE's development time focussed on more important things.

Comment: @Dukeling - No disagreement there. I hope though the important things get voted up high, and little things like this, stay low to the ground, maybe for future interns at SE to pick as low-hanging fruit :-)

Comment: Visual and SQL Server Management Studios also function in this manner (at least 2010+ and 2008R2+, respectively).

Comment: And TextPad (version 5.2.0) (which ***does*** allow you to mix code and text)

Comment: Heh... even the VBA editor in the Microsoft Office products does this. (Tested with Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications 7.0)

Comment: @Dukeling - I think the question should be: which is easier to undo? If you indent the whole line, you can undo in a single keystroke. If you indent only the selected text, you have to go in and remove all of the added whitespace which takes significantly longer.

Comment: @JDB Pretty much everything listed **allows** you to mix code and text, but that's not the **intended** use case. Is certain parts of **the same file** in TextPad syntax highlighted and not other parts? If not, the intention was most likely not to mix the two. Undo is one key press - Ctrl-Z - either way.

Comment: @Dukeling - Good point about Ctrl+Z - I've added it to my post. As to editors which intend for you to mix text and code - I don't think there are very many. Stack Overflow is a bit unique, but given the audience I think that it should lean more heavily toward code editor standards, *especially when the explicit goal is editing code*.

Comment: Everyone needs to keep in mind that we're not really talking about **indenting** code (as all listed tools do, I believe), we're talking about **marking text as code** (which happens to be done by adding 4 spaces before it). The only merit I see here is that if you do this to text that's already code, the current behaviour is fairly illogical.

Comment: @Dukeling - I think the point is usability. I am looking at *code* in my post (I know it's code). The FAQ says I need to [*indent* that code](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) by four spaces in order to apply the proper formatting. Ctrl+K is the shortcut to indent that code. At this point, any *programmer* would expect the indentation to work the same way as all code editors. But think about it this way too: How often does code, which should be located on it's own line, start in the middle of a line?

Answer (score 10):

I support this proposal. Based on the current behavior, the assumption would appear to be that we write posts like this:

> I am having an issue with foo when I pass in an uninitialized bar: var bar;
> //This is where the problem is
> foo( bar ); The defined behavior should be a return value of baz... am I misunderstanding something?

Certainly some questions come in this way, but usually from low rep users who don't use the formatting tools in the first place. In practice, I see very, very few questions *this* poorly formatted. Most low rep users know to separate their code from the rest of their content. Professional programmers who spend time with the site (and, as I said, even most hobbyists who are new to the site) are much more likely to format like so:

> I am having an issue with foo when I pass in an uninitialized bar:
>
> var bar;
> //This is where the problem is
> foo( bar );
>
> The defined behavior should be a return value of baz... am I misunderstanding something?

Now, when a knowledgable programmer who is used to using code editors selects starting from somewhere in the middle of the first line to somewhere in the middle of the last line and presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, the following happens:

> I am having an issue with foo when I pass in an uninitialized bar:
>
> var b
>
> ```
> ar;  
> //This is where the problem is  
> foo(
> ```
>
> bar );
>
> The defined behavior should be a return value of baz... am I misunderstanding something?

This then becomes a bit of a mess to clean up after<sup>1</sup>. Attempting to reverse the indent (as you might when using a code editor) leaves you with this:

> I am having an issue with foo when I pass in an uninitialized bar:
>
> var b
>
> ar;
> //This is where the problem is
> foo(
>
> bar );
>
> The defined behavior should be a return value of baz... am I misunderstanding something?

Realizing your mistake, you can now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> (once!) to get back to where you were, but at this point I've usually lost faith in the editor and have switched to using TextPad.

If we changed the behavior to match that of nearly all professional code and text editors, then someone attempting to use the formatting shortcut on the first example would end up with this:

> ```
> I am having an issue with foo when I pass in an uninitialized bar: var bar;  
> \\This is where the problem is  
> foo( bar ); The defined behavior should be a return value of baz... am I misunderstanding something?
> ```

Which can be easily undone using the same stroke which caused the formatting faux pas, and then formatted correctly by adding the necessary whitespace. (*Again, I can't think of any examples where someone has actually submitted a post like this.*)

---

In conclusion (**TL;DR**), I think this request is justified for at least the following reasons:

- It better aligns with existing conventions within the programmer community (the goal is, after all, to edit **code**, even if the post contains other non-code content)
- It is <s>easier</s> more intuitive to undo<sup>1</sup>
- It would be appropriate for (in my unresearched opinion) the majority of posts
- The current behavior is actually destructive to the original post for those caught unawares

---

<sup>1</sup> As Dukeling [pointed out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203175/make-ctrlk-indent-entire-lines-even-when-the-first-and-last-are-only-partially?noredirect=1#comment648310_203175), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> will undo the formatting in a single stroke. I don't know why this hadn't occurred to me before. I still think that pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> twice should leave you with the same content as you started with, but this "easier to undo" point is a bit weaker now.

Answer (score 1):

I really like the idea, but the only issue with me is that oftentimes I want to specifically comment variable-names within the sentence:

Say -

the user then clicks on the `JButton` and it triggers `myNewFlashyFunction` again.

So what I'd like is that, yes -  allow `Ctrl+K` to  indent irrespective of highlighting-completion, but then assign a new keyboard shortcut to *specifically* indent exactly what I've selected, and nothing more.

Comment: Even when a very long line wraps in the editor, it will still be a single line. (No line breaks.) Selecting part of such line, even if it includes the wrapping, would then still be considered a partial selection within a single line. And the feature request already excludes this case.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up. I'm not at a computer but I believe currently highlighting within a single line and Ctrl+K'ing does what you describe, and I'd actually like to keep that functionality as is. I was speaking only about the case where a _linebreak_ character's included in the selection. Would that be compatible with what you are describing?